# Name an image built from running a docker-compose file

Tags: docker-compose

If I run this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
   kibana:
      build: ./kibana
```

how can I specify the name of the resulting image which is built? At present it just defaults to the directory name plus the service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `image:` to set a name for the image.

```
version: '2'
services:
    kibana:
        image: example/imagename:latest
        build: ./kibana
```

Comment: thanks, I just assumed that the image: would only look for an existing image, so you are saying that if it is used alongside with a build: then it will build first and then tag the image?